# Create a drawable from a created imageview

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a drawable from an ImageView
I know that we can do that with getressources :

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(imageview.getId());
```

But my imageview is created programmatically, I can not get the ID even with the getID() method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you can access to the `ImageView` you cam simply call `getDrawable()` to get its drawable